# Mapbox Add Layer with Geoserver WFS binding with BBOX

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, wfs

Im trying to bind geoserver WFS GetFeature request with BBOX and adding the geojson layer to Mapbox map object so that whenever map is panned and zoomed in/out, the geojson data within the map screen visible window will be downloaded and rendered instead of loading entire table geojson data. Here is the code snippet.

```js
    function geturl(){
        return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/demo/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=demo:assets&outputFormat=application/json'
            +'&bbox='
        +map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat+','
        +map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng+','
        +map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat+','
        +map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng
    }
map.on('load', () => {
    map.addSource('city_assets', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data:geturl()
})};
```

Although I could see the points were loaded only in the viewing BBOX window for the first time, I don't see rest of the point data being downloaded and rendered when I zoom in/out or pan around.

It would be really helpful if someone can guide me if I have missed anything to make it working. Please feel free to ask for additional info. Thanks.

-Prem

Comment: You don't seem to have any code that responds to the map being moved. You probably want the `map.on('moveend', ...)` event.

Comment: Hi @steve-bennet, thanks for the reply. Im little bit confused while understanding how source and layer which is rendered will be in sync while user move the map. In other words, when we add data source on map load, how to change the data source with different set of geojson features. 

Ideally in case of leaflet or other API, bboxstrategy will take case of changing the data when map is moved but in case of mapbox, it has **'source-layer': 'bbox',** option but does not work for geojson. Any points as what it should be in moveend event handling would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Call `map.getSource("mysource").setData(...)` to update the data.